# Mongo embedded server: the single instance is not primary in replica set

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

We use Mongo in our project (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb 2.3.0.RELEASE) and we need to use it with `@Transactional`. So for testing we configure the following embedded Mongo with a replicaSet containing the single instance:

**EmbeddedMongoConfig**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class EmbeddedMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {


    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host:localhost}")
    private String dbHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database:sp-audit}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port:27017}")
    private int dbPort;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public IMongodConfig mongoConfigTest() throws IOException {
        return new MongodConfigBuilder()
            .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .withLaunchArgument("--replSet", "rs0")
            .net(new Net(dbHost, dbPort, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .cmdOptions(new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder()
                .useNoJournal(false)
                .build())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongodExecutable embeddedMongoServer() throws IOException {
        MongodExecutable server = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance().prepare(mongoConfigTest());
        server.start();
        return server;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase adminDatabase = client.getDatabase("admin");
        adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("replSetInitiate", new Document()));
        log.info("embedded replicaSet status : " + adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("replSetGetStatus", 1)));
        return client;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return dbName;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseConfiguration**

```
@Bean
public MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

Everything looks fine, but tests are failed with an Exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Sessions are not supported by the MongoDB cluster to which this client is connected
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.startSession(MongoClientImpl.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.getSession(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager.newResourceHolder(MongoTransactionManager.java:350)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager.doBegin(MongoTransactionManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionContext.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:206)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:108)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:161)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:160)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

The further research showed, that when it tries to start session, it checks if my server isPrimary or isSecondary, but gets null and fails (chain is MongoClientImpl.java:128 -> MongoClientDelegate.java:74 -> ClusterDescription.java:128)

Also, i have this in logs:

```
[cluster-ClusterId{value='5efcaf70e882a14d213c6a8f', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO  o.m.d.cluster.info() - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_GHOST, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2794500, setName='null', canonicalAddress=null, hosts=[], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='null', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=null, lastWriteDate=null, lastUpdateTimeNanos=366578580256200}
```

where you can see, that **primary='null'**.

Why it is null? How to make it be primary, as it is the single instance?

**upd**

`embedded replicaSet status` log message from `mongoClient()`:

```
embedded replicaSet status : 
Document{{
    set=rs0, 
    date=Thu Jul 02 09:19:24 MSK 2020, 
    myState=2, 
    term=1, 
    syncingTo=, 
    syncSourceHost=, 
    syncSourceId=-1, 
    heartbeatIntervalMillis=2000, 
    optimes=Document{{lastCommittedOpTime=Document{{ts=Timestamp{value=0, seconds=0, inc=0}, t=-1}}, appliedOpTime=Document{{ts=Timestamp{value=6844763807676366849, seconds=1593670763, inc=1}, t=-1}}, durableOpTime=Document{{ts=Timestamp{value=6844763807676366849, seconds=1593670763, inc=1}, t=-1}}}}, 
    lastStableCheckpointTimestamp=Timestamp{value=0, seconds=0, inc=0}, 
    members=[
        Document{{_id=0, name=127.0.0.1:27017, health=1.0, state=2, stateStr=SECONDARY, uptime=1, optime=Document{{ts=Timestamp{value=6844763807676366849, seconds=1593670763, inc=1}, t=-1}}, optimeDate=Thu Jul 02 09:19:23 MSK 2020, syncingTo=, syncSourceHost=, syncSourceId=-1, infoMessage=could not find member to sync from, configVersion=1, self=true, lastHeartbeatMessage=}}
    ], 
    ok=1.0, 
    operationTime=Timestamp{value=6844763807676366849, seconds=1593670763, inc=1}, 
    $clusterTime=Document{{clusterTime=Timestamp{value=6844763807676366849, seconds=1593670763, inc=1}, signature=Document{{hash=org.bson.types.Binary@c98f581, keyId=0}}}}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you did not configure the replica set correctly.

Comment: What did the log entry from "embedded replicaSet status : " show?

Comment: @Joe added log message

Comment: According to that replica set status, the node had not yet become primary, so it would not have been able to write to the session collection, and therefore could not support sessions.  You might create a loop that checks replSetGetStatus until a member has `state=1` or `stateStr=PRIMARY`

Comment: @Joe thanks, you helped me to understand root cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

As @Joe mentioned, the problem was so, that node inside the replicaset didn't have enough time to configure properly before entering the method annotated with `@Transactional` in tests.

I added `Thread.sleep(3000)` to `mongoClient()` and it worked for me. Not the best solution, but it's working at the moment